# name.replace xX with y if x exists

Tags: python, replace

To be more specific I'd like to figure out how to:
name.replace xX with y if x exists, if not then just replace X

I've searched this forum for an hour now, make it two, and all I find is how to replace one thing with another, which by now is pretty easy.

/a

Comment: Have you written any code yet?

Comment: Do you have some examples of input and expected output?

Comment: well I have this:<br\><br\>
`Script(x,y)<br\>
nameList = cmds.ls("%s*"%x, tr=True)<br\>
 for name in nameList:<br\>
  baseName = name.replace('%s'%x, '')<br\>`

and I want python and maya to take R:bn and bn nodes, replace *bn with eng_ - the reason for the bn and everything before is that some files have R:bn in them, others have only bn in them. Which means that the script crashes if it's one of them where the script is set to take the other. 
I'm currently cleaning my script and I want it to be versatile.

Comment: This isn't really Maya specific so you can remove the Maya tag

Comment: If this is going to be done in maya, though, you have to capture the return of the rename command - otherwise you're still not guaranteed that the new name is legit.  Always use the 'result = cmds.rename(obj1, obj2)' pattern or you will have nasty suprises

Comment: Doesn't matter its still juts basic python there's nothing in your question Maya specific. Your question is not dealing with Mayas interfaces. If you need something Maya specific your question must reflect this. You shouldn't expand questions with comments. Edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

you can just run:

```
output = name.replace('xX','y').replace('X','y')
```

Example:

```
name = "123xX345X" 
output = "123y345y"
```

Comment: thanks. this is alot simpler than I expected I must say. Since I'm no coder... quite the opposite, I have a hard time figuring out even the simplest things.

Comment: `str.replace` has no side effect, but returning value, so you should do `new_name = name.replace('xX, 'y').replace('X', 'y')`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for regular expression `x?X`:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = " test xX blabla"
>>> re.sub('x?X', 'y', text)
' test y blabla'
>>> text = " test X blabla"
>>> re.sub('x?X', 'y', text)
' test y blabla'
```

Quote from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) about `?` mark:

> The question mark character, ?, matches either once or zero times; you
>   can think of it as marking something as being optional. For example,
>   home-?brew matches either homebrew or home-brew.

Comment: You can simplify it with: x?X

Comment: thanks. I'll try the "simpler" ones above before this. I'm not sure if I'm sure if Maya takes re.sub stuff.

Comment: hey what does the x?X mean?

Comment: it means x can exist 0 or 1 times before the X so that the regular expression matches.

Answer (score 1):

```py
if 'x' in name:
    name = name.replace('xX','y')
else:
    name = name.replace('X','y')
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I guess, I'm not skilled in python, and we have no one around that does it.

Comment: I dunno know what I was expecting, maybe something really clever but this seems legit. I'll try and pop it in my exporter and see what happens. thanks

Comment: There's certainly much more clever ways to do this, but remember the most import acronym, "KISS". Keep It Simple Stupid. This will save you a bunch of headaches in the future, especially when trying to debug some 'magic' algorithm you constructed a few months back.

Comment: Two things: First, `name.replace` does nothing but return a copy of the string with the letter replaced.  You should do `name=name.replace`, which will make `name` be the new string.  Second, this answer doesn't work in all cases.  You can see this with "X123x", where the result should be "y123x".  Instead, your script returns "X123x".

Comment: @iCodez Well stated, I believed he wanted to replace the substring xX if x exists, so then it would be to add another conditional. My above answer is the direct result of a programmer who has not yet had his coffee :D

Answer (score 1):

From your example above this is a slightly more involved problem.  You have to make sure to do your renames in the root namespace or things can get nasty. You also run the risk of renaming parents before children, which will make it hard to get at the children with one call to ls.  So:

```
def replace_with_any_namespace(src, tgt):
  cmds.namespace(set=":")
  results = {}
  xforms  = cmds.ls(r=True, tr=True, l=True)  # use long paths and recursive to get all namespaces
  xforms = [i for i in xforms if src in i]    # only work on items with your target pattern
  xforms.sort()  
  xforms.reverse()  # sort and reverse means children get renamed before parents
  for item in xforms:
      path, sep, shortname = item.rpartition("|") # gets only the last name
      newname = shortname.replace(src, tgt) # this should be fine even if the namespace is there
      results[item] = cmds.ls(cmds.rename ( item,  newname), l=True)[0]
      # the paths and returns are all long paths so there are no ambiguities
  return results
```

Are you trying to move things out of their namespaces with this? Thats easier:

```
cmds.namespace(mv = ("R", ":"), force=True)
```

which moves everything in R:* to the base namespace. This will probably result in some renames, however.  You might want to put important nodes into a set before you call this so you can find them.